# Converting Column Datatype from bigint to char in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i am trying to convert one of the bigint column to char in pyspark like below.

```
data_df = df.withColumn("NELPD", df["NELPE"].cast("string").show())
```

but it is throwing error as:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Please help me

Comment: your `show()` is within the `withColumn` brackets, and it should be outside

Comment: ah!  my bad ........ Thanks KGS

Comment: Your question title seems misleading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data_df = df.withColumn("NELPD", df["NELPE"].cast("string")).show()
```

Use show() outside the withColumn brackets